# Why is Security Definer making my functions slow in Postgres?

Tags: performance, postgresql, security

After a lot of experimenting I narrowed it down to a scenario where the same function without Security Definer runs in a few milliseconds and with it for about half an hour.

This is on a top-level function which calls other functions and joins results with a few tables – so there is a lot going on.
All the lower functions are defined without Security Definer.

What exactly does the Security Definer do? Does the performance of a Security Definer function in any way depend on how many rows or columns are returned from functions/tables it uses?

We fetch quite a lot of data from our functions and tables – to the point that we noticed that reducing the number of columns returned makes queries much faster. Could it be that Security Definer checks some permissions multiple times and for large data sets it has bigger impact?

Comment: Security definer only sets user executing queries to owner of the function. It is similar to doing `set session authorization some_user`. Maybe try to execute individual queries with this user and see what takes so long. It is also possible that you have the same function/table in different schemas and it is using different versions depending on what user executes them.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński Thanks for responding! So it's equivalent to running just one command before my queries? It never does anything else?

Comment: Yes, its just changing role. I suppose more correct equivalent would be `SET ROLE` instead, since security definer does not change `session_user`.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński Thanks again! It's an even bigger mystery now then. I'm sure it always hits the same functions and tables - I run it as the owner user for my tests - just change the Security Definer option. Investigation continues...